# Chrome Inspect Element is not showing all Javascript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

The current project I am working on builds a page's javascript code based on some conditions. All the code works but when I go to the Developer Tools to see it, it is not showing. Or more like it is truncated and 3 dots added at the end.

[image: Like So]

It seems to be a change with the recent update. It is extremely annoying to not be able to see everything. Does anyone know how to make it show everything? If it helps, I'm working on a mac. Thanks.

Chrome Version 42.0.2311.152 (64-bit)

Comment: added chrome version

Comment: You should be able to see it in Sources tab

Comment: You are right. I am able to see it in the Sources tab but would be nice to be able to see it all in the Elements tab as there are some perks to it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you right click on the `<script>` tag and select "Edit as HTML", you'll be able to access the whole script, without the hyphenation.

Comment: While that works to "see" everything, you really can't do any debugging that way. So it is really only useful if you weren't the author and wanted to see what was there.

Comment: @KerryDavis sure nobody pretended anything otherwise. I'm not here to judge the usefulness of what OP tries to achieve.